# Trello json how to get lists

Tags: json, trello, manatee.trello, trello-powerup

how to Get list name from Json in trello? I need it to be able to add it in omnifocus. So an http formate that give me the list is best.

Comment: You added the `manatee.trello` tag. Are you using the Manatee.Trello .net library?

Comment: Here you go: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-boards/#api-boards-id-lists-get